# Display user profile information from firebase real-time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a website with an account information section. ON this section there is a card where I want to display a user's information. That information is stored in my realtime database like so:

[image: Firebase DB]

I have tried so far to display the user info from this database by referencing it like so:

```js
// Initialize Firebase
 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
 // Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
 const db = getFirestore(app); 
 const auth = getAuth();
 const displayName = document.getElementById('displayName');
 const displayID = document.getElementById('displayID');
 const displayEmail = document.getElementById('displayEmail');
 const displayUsername = document.getElementById('displayUsername');
 const displayLogin = document.getElementById('displayLogin');

 
     auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        // console.log(user.email);
        displayName.innerText = "Currently logged in as: " + user.email;
        displayID.innerText = "School ID: " + user.schoolID;
        displayEmail.innerText = "Email: " + user.email;
        displayUsername.innerText = "Username: " + user.username;
        displayLogin.innerText = "Account Creation: " + user.last_login;
    })
```

But when I do this all the fields display as `undefined` I'm not quite sure how to reference the database properly.

[image: HTML Form]

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <div class = "container mt-4">
        <div class = "row justify-content-center">
        <div class="card w-75 p-3 bg-dark" style="width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Account Information</h5>
              <p class="card-text">View your account's info in this section.</p>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
              <li class="list-group-item" id = "displayID">School ID: </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"  id = "displayEmail">Email Address: </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"  id = "displayUsername">Username: </li>
              <li class="list-group-item"  id = "displayLogin">Account Created: </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="card-footer">
              <a href="#" class = "btn btn-primary">
                Exit
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth) and [Firebsae Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/database) to 2 different services. The `user` object in `onAuthStateChanged` contains information that you set in Firebase authentication. See [get a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_a_users_profile) page in the documentation.

If you want to fetch data from realtime database, then you would have to query it as shown below:

```
import { onAuthStateChanged, getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";

const auth = getAuth();
const db = getDatabase();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => { 
  const snap = await get(child(dbRef, `users/${user.uid}`));
  console.log(snap.val());

  if (snap.exists()) {
    displayName.innerText = "Currently logged in as: " + user.email;
    displayID.innerText = "School ID: " + user.schoolID;
    displayEmail.innerText = "Email: " + user.email;
    displayUsername.innerText = "Username: " + user.username;
    displayLogin.innerText = "Account Creation: " + user.last_login;
  }
})
```

However, you can get most of the information like email, creation date from `user` object itself. See [update a user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile) to set display name in Firebase Auth user data.

Comment: Hello I tried this out and I got an error that dbRef is not defined so I defined it in a variable like this: `const databaseRef = ref(getDatabase());` but when I ran the code. I still get undefined from the fields. All except the email field cause its getting that from the Auth i assume. Any idea what I should do?